# basic question about continuity

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $f$ is a function defined to be $1$ when $x \in A$. and $0$ when $x \notin A$. LEt $N$ be arbitrary neighborhood of $x$ that contains points in $A$ and points not in $A$. in particular, by the way $f$ is defined, we have points $a,b$ such that $f(a) = 0$ and $f(b) = 1$. MY question is: Why does it follow that $f$ cannot be continuous at $x$ ? Im having such a hard time trying to see this. thanks

Comment: It doesn't follow. You need stronger assumptions on $x$.

Comment: Namely that _every_ neighbourhood of $x$ contains points in $A$ and points not in $A$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need $f(a)=0$ for some $a$ and $f(b)=1$ for some $b$, but the correct theorem is:

For any function $f$,

For any $x \in Dom(f)$,

If

(

For any (open) neighbourhood $S$ of $x$,

$f(t) = 0$ for some $t \in S$

$f(u) = 1$ for some $u \in S$

),

$f$ is discontinuous at $x$

~~~

You were getting confused by the English phrasing, which I find inconsistent:

"Let x be an arbitrary obj" is used to mean "For any obj x".

But when it goes into a condition, you would have to use "If for any obj x" anyway.

Comment: Yes, but how can I prove this statement?

Comment: Expand the definition of discontinuity: For any function $f$, for any $x \in Dom(f)$, $f$ is discontinuous at $x$ iff ... If you want, edit your question and write out the whole structure for the negation of continuity in the same format as I did, so that I can help you better.